# Pycharm: import Serial is NOT working but i already did "pip3 install pyserial"

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyserial

i am quite trouble why my pycharm does not recognize import serial. i am doing python code but i need to use Serial. so just from what i found:

1. i need to go to CMD, then enter "pip install pyserial" or "pip3 install pyserial"(this is what i did).
2. after that the installation seems successful, i didnt see any errors
   after that. i went back to my Pycharm and type import serial or import pyserial
3. despite that, both code are not working...

i wonder what is the problem with my Python?

-Windows 10
-Python 3.10
-Pycharm Community Version: 2021.2.3
[image]

Comment: The python used by pycharm is installed using virtualenv which is different from the python where you installed the package. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: i see. it seems this is what the tutorial i read missed. thanks ill read it~

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since I started using python 3.10.
I found that you have to download the complete pyserial package from github, unzip the entire package and edit the setup.py file and add the line 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
and then from the CMD window run python setup.py build

With that it works !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just open the terminal within the Pycharm IDE and use pip to install on there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it from pip and then using the `Python Packages` tab to install it. It worked for me when I tried that.